# Tomcat doesn't find "org.junit.Assert" even though I have JUnit jars in my classpath

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, classnotfoundexception

I am having a problem that I already looked at it a lot but still didn't find a solution. I have a test case that when executed sends a message to the console. But even with the JUnit `jar`s, it says like I don't have the `jar`s in my project.

I have a Maven project configured with Spring MVC on Eclipse and I already added JUnit `jar` to the classpath manually using the wizard. I also put the dependency in the `pom.xml`.

Inside Maven dependencies I have another Junit `jar`, version `3.8.1`. I thought it would be conflict between the `jar` added by the wizard (Version 4) and the `jar` from the dependency. But it is not.

I already tried to put version 4 on the dependency, already tried to use only the `jar` added by the wizard, or only the one from the dependency and nothing worked.

And I also have another project, it is a small one though, that the test case works on it. The small project doesn't have Spring, but is a Maven project and has exactly the same JUnit `jar`s that I have in my bigger project.

When I try to execute the test case, this error displays on the console:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/javaliproject] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert] with root cause
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
            at br.ufc.quixada.javaliproject.evaluationservice.teste.test(teste.java:17)
            at br.ufc.quixada.javaliproject.controller.RunnerController.run(RunnerController.java:30)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
            at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
            at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
            at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this problem?
The test case I was trying to run was this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Runner {
    @Test
    public static String runClass() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IOException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {

        int expected = 9;
        int obtained = 10;

        String assertionError = null;
        try {
            assertEquals(expected, obtained);
            System.out.println("This method is correct!");
        }
        catch (AssertionError ae) {
            assertionError = ae.toString();
            System.out.println(assertionError);
        }
        return "Executed!"; 
    }
}
```

Here is pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>javali</groupId>
  <artifactId>javaliproject</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <build>
        <finalName>javaliproject</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->

        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <javax.activation.version>1.1.1</javax.activation.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.0-alpha-1</javax.servlet.version>
        <javaee.web.api.version>6.0</javaee.web.api.version>
        <java.validation.version>1.1.0.Final</java.validation.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <hibernate.validator.version>5.1.0.Final</hibernate.validator.version>

        <!-- Database access -->
        <postgresql.version>9.4-1204-jdbc42</postgresql.version>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <spring.security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Java EE / Java SE dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.inject.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${java.validation.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Databases - Uses POSTGRESQL by default -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons File Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


         <dependency>
    <groupId>org.xeustechnologies</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcl-core</artifactId> 
    <version>2.7</version>
  </dependency>


    </dependencies>



</project>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. The stack trace indicates that you seem to want to use JUnit in your production, deployed code, rather than in your unit tests. And the posted code shows that you're trying to apply the Test annotation to a static method, returning a String, which is not, at all, how you define tests. And finally, you seem to be using Maven, but at the same time you're fiddling with the eclipse classpath, although the classpath should be the responsibility of the pom file. All this doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @JBNizet This is to evaluate programming assignments using test cases developed by professors. It will load the test case class from the professor and put it into the directories and when the student submit the code, my application is gonna use the professor's test case on it. But I wanna get the message from the test case to store, so that's why I am using string inside the test. This class I showed is just an example, because I am not able to load even a simple test case. I have the same class in a similar project without spring and it is working. I don't understand the problem in this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pom lists JUnit 3.81 but that version of JUnit doesn't have `org.junit.Assert`. You can use the most recent version of JUnit, but be aware that there were some changes made recently in JUnit that were not backwards compatible, so you might want to ask what version the test author(s) used.

*Edit:* Also, your pom.xml lists JUnit with scope "test" (i.e. as a dependency only for your tests), which is the right thing to do for most projects, but your project wants to use JUnit in the production code, so change it to a non-test dependency.

As Nizet said, the example test isn't a valid test.

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean with "You can the mist recent one"?

Comment: @AraújoFilho sorry, typo. You can use the most recent version (right now 4.12)

Comment: Oh, okay. Thx. Well, I already tried that, putting version 4.12. But it still doesn't work this way. As I said, I have them both: junit.jar from version 4.12 in my build path, added by the wizard, and junit.jar 3.8 added by pom. Already tried to use just the one added by the wizard, also tried to use only the pom one, and I tried to remove all of them and put only 4.12 in my pom and all those ways didn't work. That's really weird

Comment: @AraújoFilho don't add multiple versions of JUnit; that will cause problems. You have JUnit as scope "test" which is probably why it didn't work even when you only listed 4.12. I updated my answer

Comment: Thank you so much!  I changed the version and removed the <scope></scope> and now it is working the way I wanted.