# maven surefire plugin can't find supporting classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have some JUnit testcases which work when I run them them as JUnit individually, but they won't run in Maven test goal. It can't find any of the supporting classes, not even org/junit/Assert, which clearly is in my pom.xml with scope=test.  Why is that?

Here is my test case declarations and imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Map;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.batch.core.BatchStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/load-BMS-data-job-launcher-context.xml" })
public class SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest {
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest.testJobLaunching()  Time elapsed: 0.001 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest.testJobLaunching(SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest.java:79)

Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 3, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec <<< FAILURE!
com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testCountryExclusion821()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert
        at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testCountryExclusion821(BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.java:137)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.Assert
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 19 more

com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingBR()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert
        at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingBR(BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.java:165)

com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingIN()  Time elapsed: 0 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert
        at com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingIN(BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.java:193)


Results :

Failed tests:   com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.SimpleJobStepFunctionalTest.testJobLaunching()
  com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testCountryExclusion821(): org/junit/Assert
  com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingBR(): org/junit/Assert
  com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.BlueReportItemProcessorUnitTest.testSkippingIN(): org/junit/Assert

Tests run: 5, Failures: 4, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost</groupId>
  <artifactId>bluecost</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>bluecost</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <mysql.driver.version>5.1.44</mysql.driver.version>
        <db2.driver.version>10.1.0</db2.driver.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch Test -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
          <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
          <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
          <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
          <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
       </dependency>        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>                   
      </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>bluecost-batch</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First you are defining a JUnit version 3.8.X but you should use at leat a 4.X version which probably will fix the issue. Furthermore is this your real pom file ?

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194455/6309):

> Your pom lists JUnit 3.81 but that version of JUnit doesn't have `org.junit.Assert`.

So double-check which version of JUnit (4?, 5?) is actually used when you run your test individually.

The [OP JamesD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5451314/jamesd) confirms progress when settings the JUnit4 in the right order in the Eclipse project classpath.

> I have two of the three test cases running trouble free.
>
> The last one fails due to db initialization errors: nested exception is

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 
object name already exists: 
ACCOUNT_MAP in statement [create table ACCOUNT_MAP]
```

As an example, that was seen in [spring-projects/spring-boot issue 1712](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1712), and fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/4f67a2021435da0d84755865c06049194bec3bf3) and [this one](https://github.com/axibase/spring-boot/commit/1eebd0b70341df891b440aca5b507dc404d996c7)

Comment: I would suspect running individually on an IDE would infer JUnit from classpath which might be included of version `4.x`. Users generally tend to add libraries to the classpath on IDE's and forget to remove them. <= Just a guess though.

Comment: @nullpointer good point. Let us wait for the OP's input on his/her setup.

Comment: I included on top my exact pom.xml file.  Sorry, my test cases run with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class.  I'm going to change the dependency in my pom.xml to JUnit 4.x and try again.

Comment: Got a bit further, maybe, but I still have errors though that I don't have when I Run As > JUnit from Eclipse...   I no longer have errors about class errors, but I still have a Null Pointer Exception at line 79 in my first test case, which is defined like this:
  JobExecution execution= jobLauncherUtils.launchStep("ExtractAndLoad-BMS-Data-Step");
So maven can't find the jobLaucherUtils object....

Comment: @JamesD it depends on the order within the classpath, I suppose. Make sure that particular dependency (JUnit 4+) comes first, to test if changes anything.

Comment: Ok - progress.   I have two of the three test cases running trouble free.   The last one fails due to db initialization errors:  nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorExcept
ion: object name already exists: ACCOUNT_MAP in statement [create table ACCOUNT_MAP....

Comment: Curiously, the same setup works when running RunAs > JUnit.   It also works when I run that test case individually ..... it works fine!

Comment: It's as if the database initialization scripts were not executed for every test case.

Comment: @JamesD I have edited the answer with an example of your last error message.

Comment: Thanks VonC - I'm using Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE, and Spring Batch 3.0.8.RELEASE.  Not understanding which version of Spring/Spring-Batch would have those fixes you listed above...

Comment: @JamesD Yes, I was mentioning those issues just as examples, for testing.

Comment: I switched to spring 4.3.19.RELEASE (final 4.x release, I think) and re-tested.   I can run the test cases individually in maven - they all work fine one-by-one, but not when I try to run them all with mvn test.   What do you suggest?